# Excel formula/code to enable a cell to be a integer depending on the contents selected via drop down menu

Tags: excel

I am trying to use excel to calculate a MUST score (malnutrition screening). This takes three parameters into account each of which are placed in a separate column. A 'score' is then attributed to each parameter and the overall 'MUST' score can be calculated. For example, BMI >20 = 0, BMI 18.5-20 = 1, BMI <18 = 2.

The question is, if I have the three drop down options in the column for BMI, how do I then attribute a number (0,1 or 2) to that cell in order to calculate the overall MUST score?

Comment: There are gaps....if BMI=18.4, none of the conditions are true...

Answer (score 0):

There are gaps as mentioned by @Gary'sStudent but Iit seems that your values are rounded by half. Anyway, you can use this formula to calculate the number:

```
=3-MATCH(A1, {0, 18.5, 20})
```

Where `A1` is any cell containing a `BMI`.